# Is this means that hard drive will fail?

Tags: hard-drive

My question is: does this CrystalDiskInfo mean that my hard drive is going to die?

[image]

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need." - The single sentence contained in this question is confusing and does not make sense grammatically.

Comment: @BrunoBalas It is hard to know exactly how close a drive is to dying at any given point. That said, if you are the least bit concerned about the data on that drive, heed any warnings and back your data up now. At the very worst, when the drive does die (maybe tomorrow, maybe months from now) you will have it.

Answer (score 2):

A sector is called 'pending' if when the sector was read by the drive, the drive detected that the sector was partially corrupted, but the drive was able to recover the data successfully.

(If the sector was totally corrupted, the drive would have reported a bad sector to the OS, and the OS would have reported some sort of error).

Simply misreading a sector doesn't give the drive enough information to know what to do with the sector - it needs to decide if the actual sector on the platter is faulty, or if there was some sort of temporary problem. So the sector is listed as 'pending further analysis'. There are 3 main things that might have happened:

1. Data mis-read due to freak problem (e.g. vibration causing head to go out of alignment, power glitch, overheating, etc.).
2. Data mis-saved due to freak problem (same as 1).
3. Bad sector.

Next time the sector is accessed, the drive will perform additional analysis until it reaches a diagnosis (e.g. fault 2 - read data, correct it using ECC and then re-save; or fault 3 - reallocate sector). Once a diagnosis is reached the sector is taken off the pending list.

You can, if you want, run a 'surface scan' on the disk using Chkdsk. This will read every sector on the drive, and the appropriate repair mechanisms will be triggered once enough information has been gathered.